# Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, file, copy, windows-7-x64

This is the part that crashes and gives me this error is when I try to copy a file to a certain location.

```
string startupDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Tyler\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup";
File.Copy(startupDirectory, "Startup.exe");
```

I have read online and tried administrator rights and have created an "app.manifest" file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

I confirmed that in the settings, the app manifest is set to this file, but it still gives me the same error.

I have also tried this event though I didn't think it would work because it is a directory not a file:

```
File.SetAttributes(startupDirectory, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

This is WinForms and I am on windows 7 but also want it to world for windows 8+. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the name of source file name? In startupDirectory variable did you mentioned it?

Comment: A _solved_ in the title doesn't help anyone. If you found a solution apart from the given answers you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer. That way others encountering a problem of the same kind will be helped too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public static void Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName);
```

First overload is source 2nd overload is destination i think reason might be this

```
File.Copy("Startup.exe",startupDirectory);
```

Try setting the access permissions to "Full control" for the .Net user from where you are reading/saving the files.

For Access Denied Error in IIS server for particular file , please follow the below steps

```
1- Goto to C:\\Users\\Tyler\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup

2- Right click on your file -> Properties -> Pop Up of User properties appears -> click on Security tab-> click on Edit -> select Users-> tick on Allow Full Control -> Click Ok
```

This will surely solve the Access denied problem

An UnauthorizedAccessException means one of 3 things:

- The caller does not have the required permission.
- path is a directory.
- path specified a read-only file.

Comment: I am confused on the first option... The second and third did not work and for the forth one I cant find select IIS_IUSRS

Comment: @Tyler13579 give full control to user

Comment: full control is already checked and greyed out so I cant change it

Comment: the second option gave me this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The target file "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" is a directory, not a file.

Comment: @Tyler13579 try with this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: try File.Copy("Startup.exe",startupDirectory,true);

Comment: I am looking at the website though and will try that

Answer (score 3):

This exception is triggered by a Windows error.  It does not have a dedicated "this make absolutely no sense" error code, it just produces an "access denied" error code.  Which .NET translates to a UnauthorizedAccessException.

The "makes no sense" problem here is that you are trying to copy a **directory** with a file copy method.  Directories are not files.  Copying a directory requires creating a new directory first, then copying all of the files in the directory.  .NET has a method for that, most C# programmers tend to think it is the 'wrong' namespace.  It is Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory().

But you'll need to think a bit more about this problem, it of course doesn't make sense to call the new directory "startup.exe".  A probably meant to copy a *specific* file from the Startup directory, we can't guess what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    File.Copy(startupDirectory, "Startup.exe", true);
    File.SetAttributes("Startup.exe", FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run Visual Studio with Administrative Rights. (Assuming Windows7, Right-click on Visual Studio icon in the start menu and click "Run as Administrator")