# Access Denied error when using XmlReader.Create

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I cant figure out this exception. Maybe I am using this `xmlReader` the wrong way?

> 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
>
> Additional information: Access to the path 'c:\example\extract' is
>   denied.

I have checked the rights on the **folder/files** and given full writes to **users/administrators** on my pc. 
Any suggestions?

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("c:\\example\\extract");
 XElement el = XElement.Load(reader);
 reader.Close();

 var items = el.Elements("values").Elements("values").DescendantNodes();

 items = from item in el.Elements("values").Elements("values").Descendants()
 where item.Attribute("name").Value == "name"
 select item.FirstNode;

 foreach(XNode node in items) {
     Console.WriteLine(node.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: Are you running your app in Administrator mode then? Also you can use relative path to your bin directory by starting like this "\\extract.xml". Why specifically c drive?

Comment: XmlReader is for reading an XML file.  It looks like you are specifying the directory.  Is "extract" a file or directory?

Comment: Is `extract` a directory ?  XmlReader.Create expects the full path including filename, e.g. c:\\example\\extract\\output.xml

Comment: @JeffPrince it is a directory.. I am trying to read, but I thought I may be using XmlReader wrong

Comment: there is no file being references in your string ""c:\\example\\extract"", I would use the `Path.Combine(drive, folder, folder, file)` so that this handles the directory structure and gets the file.  Put a break point in and make sure you're actually getting in and reading the file

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27555923/3922214

> An UnauthorizedAccessException means one of 3 things:
>
> -The caller does not have the required permission.
>
> -path is a directory.
>
> -path specified a read-only file.

There's a few things you can try. Make sure there are no directories that have the same name as the file you are trying to create. Also, try running VS with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the path wrong and not referencing a file in the path. All the input suggested worked.