# How to access the username and password from appsettings file to program.cs in c#

Tags: c#, appsettings

I am implementing a console application to build application pool status.I referred [check the status of IIS Application Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613513/check-the-status-of-iis-application-pool.Instead) of getting the username and password from database,I wanted to get them from appsettings.json.

The problem I am having is the value (the username jandi) doesn't pass to the program.cs, it passes a null value.

I have included my code.

**program.cs**

```
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Timers;

namespace processstatus
{
    class Program
    {
       

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double interval60Minutes = 5 * 5 * 1000; // milliseconds to one hour
            Timer checkForTime = new Timer(interval60Minutes);
            checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
            checkForTime.Enabled = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting..");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            GetApplicationPoolNames();
        }

        public static string GetApplicationPoolNames()
        {
            string UName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User"];
            string Pwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pass"];
            string ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
            DirectoryEntries appPools = null;
            try
            {
                appPools = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://" + ServerName + "/W3SVC/AppPools", UName, Pwd).Children;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("serviceLogic -> InsertStatus() -> IIS Pool App Region -> DirectoryEntries -> Error: ", ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            Log.Information("IIS App Pool Section Started for " + System.Environment.MachineName.ToString());

            try
            {
                foreach (DirectoryEntry appPool in appPools)
                {
                    Log.Information("App Pool : " + appPool.Name.ToString());
                    int intStatus = 0;
                    string status = "";
                    try
                    {
                        if (appPool.Name.ToString().ToLower().Trim() == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"].ToString().ToLower().Trim())
                        {
                            Log.Information("Process Started for App Pool : " + appPool.Name.ToString());

                            intStatus = (int)appPool.InvokeGet("AppPoolState");
                            switch (intStatus)
                            {
                                case 2:
                                    status = "Running";
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    status = "Stopped";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    status = "Unknown";
                                    break;
                            }

                            //Store status info to db or file Logic goes here..

                            //Start App pool, If any application pool status is not Running.
                            if (status != "Running")
                                appPool.Invoke("Start", null);

                            Log.Information("Process Completed for App Pool : " + appPool.Name.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error("serviceLogic -> InsertStatus() -> IIS Pool App Region -> Error: ", ex.Message);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("serviceLogic -> InsertStatus() -> IIS Pool App Region -> DirectoryEntries -> Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
            return "Message";
        }
    }
}
```

**Appsettings.json file**

```
   {
  "AppSettings": {
    "User": "jandi",
    "Pass": "jandi123",
    "Server": "abc"
  }
}
```

Can someone please let me know the error in the above code?

Comment: Is this .NET Framework, .NET Core or .NET 5? Also, `ConfigurationManager` is for .NET Framework's app.config file, not for .NET Core's appsettings.json file

Comment: @ProgmanI refereed it already.So inorder to do this is it a must to use mvc architecture?Is there a way to accomplish the requirment without using mvc?

Comment: You don't need to use ASP.NET Core. You can just install the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration packages (https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=microsoft.extensions.configuration), I think the Json one should be enough

Comment: ConfigurationManager reads the _app.config_ file not an _appsettings.json_. You need to add a proper app.config with the _appSettings_ section and then your code should work (provided that it compiles correctly)

Comment: This blog post seems to address the point [How to read custom configurations from appsettings.json](https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-read-custom-configuration-from-appsettings-json/) from a console application in net core

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core console apps, you can use *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration* to read appsettings.json files, as has been already pointed out in the comments. I've used this a couple of times and it seems to work just fine. You can then use something like this in your Program class:

```
private static IConfiguration _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
    .Build();
```

You can then read the appsettings variables via the _configuration variable.